# windows Qt C++ opencv + cv::dnn::Net

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I try to create project with yolov4 to detect object. Use Qt C++, MingGW 64. I build opencv for Windows and try to crate project:

my *.pro:

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

INCLUDEPATH += E:\opencv\build\install\include
INCLUDEPATH += E:\opencv\source\modules\dnn\include

LIBS += -L"E:/opencv/build/install/x64/mingw/bin"
LIBS += -llibopencv_core455 -llibopencv_highgui455 -llibopencv_imgproc455 -llibopencv_features2d455 -llibopencv_calib3d455 -llibopencv_imgcodecs455 -llibopencv_video455 -llibopencv_videoio455

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/dnn/all_layers.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::ifstream classNamesFile("../model/OpenCV4YOLO4/coco.names");

        std::vector<std::string> classNamesVec;
        if (classNamesFile.is_open())
        {
            std::string className = "";
            while (std::getline(classNamesFile, className))
                classNamesVec.push_back(className);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < classNamesVec.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << i + 1 << "\t" << classNamesVec[i].c_str() << std::endl;
        }

        cv::String cfg = "../model/OpenCV4YOLO4/yolov4.cfg";
        cv::String weight = "../model/OpenCV4YOLO4/yolov4.weights";

        cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromDarknet(cfg, weight);

        int currFrame = 0;




            cv::VideoCapture cap(0);//open camera
            cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));

        cv::Mat frame;

        while (true)
        {
            std::cout<<"read "<<currFrame<<" frame"<<std::endl;
            ++currFrame;
            cap >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
            {
                break;
            }

            cv::Mat inputBlob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(frame, 1.0 / 255, cv::Size(608, 608), cv::Scalar());
            net.setInput(inputBlob);

            //
            std::vector<cv::String> outNames = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < outNames.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << "output layer name : " << outNames[i].c_str() << std::endl;
            }

            std::vector<cv::Mat> outs;
            net.forward(outs, outNames);

            float* data;
            cv::Mat scores;

            std::vector<cv::Rect> boxes;
            std::vector<int> classIds;
            std::vector<float> confidences;
            int centerX, centerY, width, height, left, top;

            float confidenceThreshold = 0.2;
            double confidence;

            cv::Point classIdPoint;

            //
            for (size_t i = 0; i<outs.size(); ++i){
                data = (float*)outs[i].data;
                for (int j = 0; j < outs[i].rows; ++j, data += outs[i].cols){
                    scores = outs[i].row(j).colRange(5, outs[i].cols);
                    minMaxLoc(scores, 0, &confidence, 0, &classIdPoint);
                    if (confidence > confidenceThreshold){
                        centerX = (int)(data[0] * frame.cols);
                        centerY = (int)(data[1] * frame.rows);
                        width = (int)(data[2] * frame.cols);
                        height = (int)(data[3] * frame.rows);
                        left = centerX - width / 2;
                        top = centerY - height / 2;

                        classIds.push_back(classIdPoint.x);
                        confidences.push_back((float)confidence);
                        boxes.push_back(cv::Rect(left, top, width, height));
                    }
                }
            }

            std::vector<int> indices;
            cv::dnn::NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.3, 0.2, indices);

            cv::Scalar rectColor, textColor; //
            cv::Rect box, textBox;
            int idx;
            cv::String className;
            cv::Size labelSize;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < indices.size(); ++i) {
                idx = indices[i];
                className = classNamesVec[classIds[idx]];

                labelSize = getTextSize(className, cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1, 0);
                box = boxes[idx];
                textBox = cv::Rect(cv::Point(box.x - 1, box.y),
                               cv::Point(box.x + labelSize.width, box.y - labelSize.height));
                rectColor = cv::Scalar(idx * 11 % 256, idx * 22 % 256, idx * 33 % 256);
                textColor = cv::Scalar(255 - idx * 11 % 256, 255 - idx * 22 % 256, 255 - idx * 33 % 256);

                rectangle(frame, box, rectColor, 2, 8, 0);
                rectangle(frame, textBox, rectColor, -1, 8, 0);
                putText(frame, className.c_str(), cv::Point(box.x, box.y - 2), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, textColor, 1, 8);
            }

            cv::imshow("OpenCV - YOLO", frame);
            cv::waitKey(1);
            
        }

    return a.exec();
}
```

but when I try to bulid the project I get an error:

```
main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::readNetFromDarknet(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

undefined reference to `cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::Net::~Net()'

undefined reference to `cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::blobFromImage(cv::_InputArray const&, double, cv::Size_<int> const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, bool, bool, int)'

undefined reference to `cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::Net::setInput(cv::_InputArray const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, double, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'

 undefined reference to `cv::dnn::dnn4_v20211220::NMSBoxes(std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > > const&, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&, float, float, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, float, int)'
```

I try to find any solutions, but couldn't anything

Please, help. Is anyone know what what is problem and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: linker errors. definitely a build issue. you need to make a clean build. this `dnn4_v20211220` usually happens when people try to build a newer version of opencv with outdated build artefacts. you can google for that string and you'll find such issues.

Comment: thanks for answer. about E:\opencv\build\install. yes it's correct. About "try to build a newer version of opencv with outdated build artefacts" what you mean? I try to google this error but not find any...

Comment: The *.dll included here: LIBS += -L"E:/opencv/build/install/x64/mingw/bin"

Comment: I am sorry I missed that. I guess my morning coffee hadn't kicked in yet..